# Can you please help me change the demo code? I want to map a different function

Tags: complex, demonstrations

Initialisation code:

```
refunc = ComplexExpand[Re[(x + I*y)^6 + 6 (x + I*y) + 10]];
imfunc = ComplexExpand[Im[(x + I*y)^6 + 6 (x + I*y) + 10]];
contrans[func_, xtrans_, ytrans_] := 
func /. {x -> xtrans, y -> strains};
```

Manipulation:

```
Manipulate[
Grid[{{Text@"contour", 
Text@"image"}, {ParametricPlot[{{r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]}}, {t, 0, 
  2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.003]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> {295}], 
ParametricPlot[{{contrans[refunc, r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]], 
   contrans[imfunc, r*Cos[t], r*Sin[t]]}}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.003]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-70, 90}, {-80, 80}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> {295}]}}], {{r, 1}, 0.5, 2}, 
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

This is from a Wolfram Demonstration Project.

I would like to use this code to map f(z)=z^n rather than f(z)=z^6 + 6z +10 as they have used here. Each time I try, the image part of the plot remains blank, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is n in your case?

Comment: n is any natural number (what I want to show is f(z)=z^n has n roots) @niloderoock

Comment: You have used a specific value for the plot, I assume?

Comment: Do you mean a specific value of n? If so, no I haven't. I just tried using n=3 but I'm not getting any winds on the image side. I should have 3 winds, instead I get a circle. Do you think I am expecting the wrong thing?

Comment: I found the error it is a typo !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

y -> strains should be y-> ytrans